# Python 2.7 - statsmodels - formatting and writing summary output

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, statsmodels

I'm doing logistic regression using `pandas 0.11.0`(data handling) and `statsmodels 0.4.3` to do the actual regression, on Mac OSX Lion.

I'm going to be running ~2,900 different logistic regression models and need the results output to csv file and formatted in a particular way.

Currently, I'm only aware of doing `print result.summary()` which prints the results (as follows) to the shell:

```
 Logit Regression Results                           
  ==============================================================================
 Dep. Variable:            death_death   No. Observations:                 9752
 Model:                          Logit   Df Residuals:                     9747
 Method:                           MLE   Df Model:                            4
 Date:                Wed, 22 May 2013   Pseudo R-squ.:                -0.02672
 Time:                        22:15:05   Log-Likelihood:                -5806.9
 converged:                       True   LL-Null:                       -5655.8
                                         LLR p-value:                     1.000
 ===============================================================================
                   coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 age_age5064    -0.1999      0.055     -3.619      0.000        -0.308    -0.092
 age_age6574    -0.2553      0.053     -4.847      0.000        -0.359    -0.152
 sex_female     -0.2515      0.044     -5.765      0.000        -0.337    -0.166
 stage_early    -0.1838      0.041     -4.528      0.000        -0.263    -0.104
 access         -0.0102      0.001    -16.381      0.000        -0.011    -0.009
 ===============================================================================
```

I will also need the odds ratio, which is computed by `print np.exp(result.params)`, and is printed in the shell as such:

```
age_age5064    0.818842
age_age6574    0.774648
sex_female     0.777667
stage_early    0.832098
access         0.989859
dtype: float64
```

What I need is for these each to be written to a csv file in form of a very lon row like (am not sure, at this point, whether I will need things like `Log-Likelihood`, but have included it for the sake of thoroughness):

```
`Log-Likelihood, age_age5064_coef, age_age5064_std_err, age_age5064_z, age_age5064_p>|z|,...age_age6574_coef, age_age6574_std_err, ......access_coef, access_std_err, ....age_age5064_odds_ratio, age_age6574_odds_ratio, ...sex_female_odds_ratio,.....access_odds_ratio`
```

I think you get the picture - a very long row, with all of these actual values, and a header with all the column designations in a similar format.

I am familiar with the `csv module` in Python, and am becoming more familiar with `pandas`.  Not sure whether this info could be formatted and stored in a `pandas dataframe` and then written, using `to_csv` to a file once all ~2,900 logistic regression models have completed; that would certainly be fine.  Also, writing them as each model is completed is also fine (using `csv module`).

UPDATE:

So, I was looking more at statsmodels site, specifically trying to figure out how the results of a model are stored within classes.  It looks like there is a class called 'Results', which will need to be used.  I think using inheritance from this class to create another class, where some of the methods/operators get changed might be the way to go, in order to get the formatting I require.  I have very little experience in the ways of doing this, and will need to spend quite a bit of time figuring this out (which is fine).  If anybody can help/has more experience that would be awesome!

Here is the site where the classes are laid out: [statsmodels results class](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/dev/internal.html#model)

Comment: Added an update to the bottom of this question.  Please take a look!

Comment: If you consider your update an answer, please consider a self-answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no premade table of parameters and their result statistics currently available.

Essentially you need to stack all the results yourself, whether in a list, numpy array or pandas DataFrame depends on what's more convenient for you.

for example, if I want one numpy array that has the results for a model, llf and results in the summary parameter table, then I could use

```
res_all = []
for res in results:
    low, upp = res.confint().T   # unpack columns 
    res_all.append(numpy.concatenate(([res.llf], res.params, res.tvalues, res.pvalues, 
                   low, upp)))
```

But it might be better to align with pandas, depending on what structure you have across models.

You could write a helper function that takes all the results from the results instance and concatenates them in a row.

(I'm not sure what's the most convenient for writing to csv by rows)

*edit:*

Here is an example storing the regression results in a dataframe

https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/sandbox/multilinear.py#L21

the loop is on line 159.

summary() and similar code outside of statsmodels, for example http://johnbeieler.org/py_apsrtable/ for combining several results, is oriented towards printing and not to store variables.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to read all of that and for responding!  I will give it a try/experiment with it tomorrow!  I was, originally, trying to iterate over results.summary() - which doesn't work!

Comment: Thank you again for this! Sorry it took longer then I said it would to get back to you.  I tried the `res_all=[]` example you gave and it returned a `TypeError: 'BinaryResultsWrapper' object is not iterable`.  Any ideas?  I will also take a look at github you posted.

Comment: Also, looking at this http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/_images/inheritance-094830692a2117caf718ad013bd23e2a57db7b6d.png it looks like I'm dealing with the 'BinaryResultsWrapper' as opposed to just results...

Comment: Found that by calling, for instance, `result.pvalues`, these results can be displayed!  Thank you for your help!  I will accept this solution.

Answer (score 5):

```
write_path = '/my/path/here/output.csv'
with open(write_path, 'w') as f:
    f.write(result.summary().as_csv())
```

Comment: Please provide some context for your answer. Code alone almost never makes for a good answer

Comment: @swu4, super answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

- results.params : for coefficient
- results.pvalues : for p-values

BTW you can use dir(results) to find out all the attribute of an object

Answer (score 2):

I found this formulation to be a little more straightforward. You can add/subtract columns by following the syntax from the examples (pvals,coeff,conf_lower,conf_higher).

```
import pandas as pd     #This can be left out if already present...

def results_summary_to_dataframe(results):
    '''This takes the result of an statsmodel results table and transforms it into a dataframe'''
    pvals = results.pvalues
    coeff = results.params
    conf_lower = results.conf_int()[0]
    conf_higher = results.conf_int()[1]

    results_df = pd.DataFrame({"pvals":pvals,
                               "coeff":coeff,
                               "conf_lower":conf_lower,
                               "conf_higher":conf_higher
                                })

    #Reordering...
    results_df = results_df[["coeff","pvals","conf_lower","conf_higher"]]
    return results_df
```

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a built-in method documented in the documentation [here](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.iolib.summary.Summary.as_csv.html#statsmodels.iolib.summary.Summary.as_csv):

```
f = open('csvfile.csv','w')
f.write(result.summary().as_csv())
f.close()
```

I believe this is a much easier (and clean) way to output the summaries to csv files.