# Python 2.7- statsmodels - result.conf_int()

Tags: python, python-2.7, statsmodels

This post is an addition to the post found here: [Python 2.7 - statsmodels - formatting and writing summary output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705598/python-2-7-statsmodels-formatting-and-writing-summary-output)

I got everything formatted how I need, except the confidence interval is giving me problems.

I have tried a number of different things including:

```
low, high = result.conf_int()
```

Which, when printed, returns:

```
 low
 Out[260]: 0

 high
 Out[261]: 1
```

Similarly, I've tried:

```
low, up = result.conf_int().T
```

But get the error:

```
 ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Same thing when I try:

```
for item in result.conf_int().T:
     low, high = item
     print low
     print high

ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I also tried looking it up both [here](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.ARResults.conf_int.html) (I have 0.4.3 and couldn't find a page for this version) and [here](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.html).  Neither were helpful in solving this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've put in pandas object to the model, so conf_int will return a DataFrame. Try something like

```
conf_int = results.conf_int()
print conf_int[0]
print conf_int[1]
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following:

```
print('confidence interval of cofficients: \n', Results.conf_int())
```